# How to prevent application from writing to disk?

Tags: linux, security

I want to execute an application on my server but I do not want this application to modify any files. I expect the application to read files and to output to stdout/stderr. However, I don't know exactly what the application may try to do because it was provided to me by someone else.

What's the easiest way to accomplish this in Linux? I'm running Red Hat 5.

One way I can think of is to create a new user who only has read-level access. Is there another way to do this without creating a user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [chroot command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) to restrict the process to a sandbox directory.

If copying the necessary files is not feasible:
Use "bind mount" in order to create a link from inside the chroot directory to outer filesystem. Run the mount command out of chroot.

```
mount /external/path /chroot/sandbox/ref_to_external -o bind
```

As you suggested: You could run your application as another user:

```
/bin/su - limitedUser -c "/path/to/xxxx"
```

Explanation:

```
 /bin/su : switch user
 - : option to su, make it a login session (source profile for the user)
 limitedUser : user to become
 -c "/path/to..." : command to run
```

Make sure that `limitedUser` belongs to a group which has only read+execute but no write rights.